# Qt5 QNetworkAccessManager finished signal never emits

Tags: qt5, signals-slots, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

I have a very confusing problem.

I had a simple project that was downloading files from some ftp servers. It worked very good.

Then, I tried implementing that same code into a larger project (first one was a Console App, and the second one is GUI, but I don't think that changes anything..).

After doing some debugging it seems to me that `finished()` signal from `QNetworkAccessManager` somehow never gets emitted (or received). 
Again, the exact same lines of code work as a separate project.

downloader.h

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADER_H
#define DOWNLOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

class Downloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Downloader(QObject *parent = 0);



signals:

    void dloadend();
    void printed();

public slots:
    void replyFinished (QNetworkReply *reply);
    void doDownload(QUrl url);
    void printDLend();

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
};

#endif // DOWNLOADER_H
```

downloader.cpp

```
#include "downloader.h"

Downloader::Downloader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}
void Downloader::doDownload(QUrl url)
{
    qDebug()<<"entry: doDownload\n";
    QNetworkRequest req(url);
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(printDLend()));//SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager -> get(req);
    qDebug()<<"exit: doDownload\n";
}

void Downloader::replyFinished (QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug()<<"entry: reply\n";

    if(reply->error()) {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    else

    {
        qDebug() << "Download finished!";

        QFile *file = new QFile("C:/users/jelicicm/Desktop/test1.hex");

        if(file->open(QFile::Append))
        {
            file->write(reply->readAll());
            file->flush(); file->close();
            qDebug() <<"Downloaded file size:" <<file->size() <<"Bytes";
            qDebug() <<"File name: "<< file->fileName();
;
        }
        delete file;
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
    manager->deleteLater();
    emit dloadend();

}
```

mainwindow.cpp (important part)

```
void MainWindow::on_actionDownloadFirmwareImage_triggered()
{
    Downloader d;

    QUrl url("ftp://ftp.xenbase.org/pub/Genomics/JGI/Xenla6.0/Xenla_6.0_JGI_Gene_Models.fasta.tgz");

    qDebug() << "url, debug";
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(url.toDisplayString());

    d.doDownload(url);

    QObject::connect(&d,SIGNAL(dloadend()),this, SLOT(printDLend()));
}
```

Can't get my head around this.

Any help is welcome,

Thanks!

EDIT> More info:
Debugger posts this>

url, debug

entry: doDownload

exit: doDownload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create object `Downloader` on stack and it is deleted right after your function exits. You must create object using `new`, and provide `MainWindow` object as parent, so after you close MainWindow, the object will be destroyed.
If the download finish, you still need to destroy the object, so simply connect the `dloadend()` signal to `deleteLater()` slot, Qt loop will delete your object right after all signal are processed.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_actionDownloadFirmwareImage_triggered()
{
    Downloader *d = new Downloader(this);

    QUrl url("ftp://example.com/some.file.tgz");

    qDebug() << "url, debug";
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(url.toDisplayString());

    d->doDownload(url);

    QObject::connect(d,SIGNAL(dloadend()),this, SLOT(printDLend()));
    QObject::connect(d,SIGNAL(dloadend()), d, SLOT(deleteLater()));
}
```

Comment: You're right. It didn't occur to me at all.

Thanks!